# Warnings in command line become errors in php with ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to use ghostscript to scan a PDF and tell me what pages are color and which are black and white.  I have written up a script that prints out each page and its color with ghostscript. When I run this script using the command line I get the following warning:

```
Page 56
**** Warning: Short look-up table in the Indexed color space was padded with 0's.
```

This didn't seem to be a problem because the script continued until it did all 356 remaining pages.  However when I ran this script in PHP using the exec() or system() functions I get the following at Page 56:

```
Page 56 
Error: /ioerror in --run-- Operand stack: --dict:11/20(L)-- --dict:10/18(L)-- 3092695 
Indexed DeviceCMYK 56 
(\000\000\000\000\b\001\016\000\033\0040\000\005\001\t\000\002\000\003\000\)\007K\0008\bh\000N\017\224\000W\016\247\000r\034\327\000t\033\334\000\016\001\036\000D\t\177\000]\025\264\0003\007b\000S\021\234\000m\032\317\000\275t\007\000o9\t\000i\027\311\000;\to\000c\026\272\000,\006T\000\035\0047\000\022\002#\000\177jj\016uab\006r^_\005\f\t\t\000~ii\r\204oo\024SBC\000\005\003\003\000]KL\000o[\\\003\277\255\253\346\034\025\027\000@34\000\025\017\020\000gSU\001\275\254\252\335\265\245\243\255vac\007\271\252\247\312\221{z%\262\242\240\234%\034\035\0007+,\000\245\222\220X\212ut\033...) --nostringval-- 
Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1910 1 3 %oparray_pop 1909 1 3 %oparray_pop 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 57 1 346 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- 3092695 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 
Dictionary stack: --dict:1162/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:82/200(L)-- --dict:82/200(L)-- --dict:108/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:291/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:23/30(L)-- --dict:6/8(L)-- --dict:27/40(L)-- --dict:1/1(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/1(ro)(G)-- --dict:5/16(L)-- 
Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 9 Unrecoverable error: ioerror in quit 
Operand stack: --nostringval-- --nostringval--
```

After I get this error the PHP script will stop and not continue like it does when I run the program in the command line.  Why would I get this error in PHP only, and how can I correct it to ignore those warnings/errors?

Here are the flags that are on ghostscript when I call it:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=display -dDisplayHandle=0 
   -dDisplayFormat=(values for DISPLAY_COLORS_RGB|DISPLAY_DEPTH_8|DISPLAY_LITTLEENDIAN|DISPLAY_BOTTOMFIRST) 
   test.pdf -f
```

Also I am using ghostscript-9.05

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your PHP calling Ghostscript finds the very same version as does your commandline?

Isn't it possible that you have 2 different instances of Ghostscript installed at 2 different locations?

You should run

```
gs -v
```

and

```
gs -h
```

from within PHP as well as from the commandline to see if they are the same.